# Problems with owl carousel not working

Tags: javascript, css, owl-carousel

I am looking at this code for someone and have no idea what could be the problem.

url is http://www.stfphc.org/new-site/

Comment: You only have one slide. What's the point of that?

Comment: You just have on item on the slide, there is nothing else to animate.

Comment: What problem are you referring to? The slider is the least of your worries on that page, there are three h1's, the layout is broken (content escaping the content div) etc.

Comment: I appreciate your input guys.  the code is a mess, I know it.  He used both inline and internal css,  I haven't even started to look at that.  I wanted to start with the carousel.  I know very little about this carousel, so I thought I would reach out to you guys.  I see in the main.css there two slider images set up for the carousel.  I changed the line to show loop :  true.  Not sure what to do from here.  The url is

Comment: The url is  http://jandswebsitedesigns.com/family

Answer (score 0):

You can change slider settings for the loop

```
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                autoPlay: true,
                navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
                slideSpeed : 10000,
                paginationSpeed : 500,
                loop:true
            });
```

Comment: I appreciate your input guys. the code is a mess, I know it. He used both inline and internal css, I haven't even started to look at that. I wanted to start with the carousel. I know very little about this carousel, so I thought I would reach out to you guys. I see in the main.css there two slider images set up for the carousel. I changed the line to show loop : true. Not sure what to do from here. The url is – jandswebsitedesigns.com/family

Answer (score 0):

1. You should update ow-carousel to current version [owl-carousel-2](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)
2. Also you can update your code

```js
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    autoPlay: true,
      navigation : false,   // Show next and prev buttons
      slideSpeed : 10000,
      paginationSpeed : 500,
      loop:true,
       responsiveClass:true,
       responsive:{
        0:{
         items:1,
         nav:false
        },
        640:{
         items:1,
         nav:false
        },
        800:{
         items:1,
         nav:false
        }
       }
   });
```